# What are the pros and cons for covering a steel fence post in wood?

Tags: fence, post

While this looks nice on picture and it theory I am seeing a couple of problems here:
-I don't think that the hollow box design will stand the time and the weather test. The screws are set on the side of the 2x4s in order to make the box stay in one piece. The 2x4s might crack over time especially if they sit outdoor
-the bottom side will be allways in contact with the soil unless something is put the so there is a good chance that this will rot in time
 Please share your experience and confirm if the above are true or false assumptions, based on your experience

[image]

Comment: The #1 reason to back steel with wood is to give something to nail into.

Comment: pre-drill to help prevent splitting, and use a section of pvc lumber at the bottom to keep it off the ground.

Comment: @ Harper yes that is the main reason 
@dandavis  I don't know if the pre drilling will work;thanks for the PVC trick! !!

Comment: One think that I see happening is the cover boards shrinking and the wood box becoming loose..then the wind will start banging this against the post

Answer (score 1):

Wood being used to cover or encase a metal post, I would consider a reasonable and acceptable practice.  The wood would need to be protected from the elements as any other application where wood is exposed.  Many paints, stains and wood treatments are used for just such purpose.  Ongoing maintenance will be necessary to ensure proper protection.  Some wood products display a natural ability to stand up well when exposed to the elements, i.e. Redwood and Cedar. Additionally, the newer composite materials stand up very well to wind, rain and sun. Construction with metal and glass is a relatively recent phenomenon. Stone and wood has been use since before recorded history.